# SQLite with Local Database, is it possible?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create an app. I've just started developing with Android. I read that SQLite is to save data in private database and there is Local Storage to save things in a file for example. But the thing is, I think that saving data in a file, reading everything and then showing to the user would be effective in my case (small application) but boring. Is there a way to create a Databse with SQLite? I mean, I am using it but it`s not working, everytime I close the app and after sometime open it again all the data is vanished. As if it was temporary database, volatile. Am I doing something wrong or there is no way but using Local Storage since I dont have any database on the internet.

```
package com.example.daniel.sm;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 08/03/18.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SMdb";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "equipamentos";
    private static final String COL_1 = "id";
    private static final String COL_2 = "equipamento";
    private static final String COL_3 = "quantidade";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" (" +
                COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                COL_2+" TEXT,"+COL_3+" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public int addEquipment(String nome, int quantidade){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2,nome);
        values.put(COL_3,quantidade);
        int newlyId = (int) db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
        return newlyId;
    }

    public int updateEquipment(Equipamento equipamento){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2,equipamento.getNome());
        values.put(COL_3,equipamento.getQuantidade());

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,COL_1+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(equipamento.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteEquipment(Equipamento equipamento){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL_1+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(equipamento.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    public Equipamento getEquipment(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{COL_1,COL_2,COL_3},COL_1+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return new Equipamento(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getInt(2));
    }

    public List<Equipamento> getAllEquipment(){
        List<Equipamento> listEquipamento = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Equipamento equipamento = new Equipamento();
                equipamento.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                equipamento.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
                equipamento.setQuantidade(cursor.getInt(2));
                listEquipamento.add(equipamento);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return  listEquipamento;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you show here looks correct. It should create a database and save data that can be loaded the second time you run it. How are you running the app? Do you only run it directly from Android Studio?

Comment: I think it might be your onUpgrade function doing it, you would normally check that the two int parameters aren't equal, if they are then there's no need to upgrade so you don't need to do the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. I believe from memory in this case int i would be the current version and int i1 is the new version

Comment: I use my own smartphone to run the app. I'll try to use Room Database because I dont see other options.

Comment: You can also use [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) for storing data, it's not a library but just a java file which saves the data using Android shared preferences. I preferred it over SQLite database in one of my app where data was less. Also, if you really want to go with SQLite database then use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead of the default SQLiteOpenHelper to skip the boilerplate code and ease of accessing/saving/updating the database. These both ways work great as I've used them.

Comment: Consider Room or ObjectBox

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a local database for the application, it's used to persist data between multiple application launch.

So in your case, just use SQLite, you don't need to write/read a file

But instead of using `SQLiteDatabase` directly and write all your request, you can use **Room**, it's an abstraction layer over **SQLite** and it's pretty simple to use. You just need an entity, a dao and a database class.

You can implement it this way :

*User.java*

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and setters are ignored for brevity,
    // but they're required for Room to work.
}
```

*UserDao.java*

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<User> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insert(User user);

    @Update
    void update(User user);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);

}
```

*Database.java*

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

And finally in your application, you can just instantiate your database this way :

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

For more informations about the Room Database, check the Android guide about it : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try to understand and do that.

Comment: There are also other ORMs (object-relational mapping) for android if Room doesn't suit you.